# Is there a kind of opensource framework base on dpdk, also implement userspace tcp/ip protocol?

Tags: tcp, frameworks, multicast, dpdk, dpdk-pmd

Besides, this framework support multithread construct, provide POSIX_like interface(including epoll), also support multicast.
Thank you all!

Comment: for posix-like interface you probably want your operating system. One reason DPDK is fast is that it's *not* posix-like

Answer (score 0):

you may try using vpp by FDio.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to [UDPDK](https://github.com/leoll2/UDPDK) which is the most usable and closest to UDP like implementation (with DPDK under the hood) that I have found so far though you have to add/tweak some things before integrating in prod code